# Salesforce ant migration tool and own required test coverage value

Tags: ant, salesforce, force.com

Does somebody know about the following scenario:

I need to

- calculate an apex code coverage during deployment with Migration tool
- give the result on console
- after that I need to decide about continuation deployment. If I will give less that 88% (for instance) of code coverage I need to mark build as failed in Jenkins and to stop a deployment, in other case I can go ahead.

**So, what I need is just ability to set any value (greater 75) as required test coverage for my project.**

Comment: The correct answer was added here http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/16832/2423